# How to write result of a for loop to a dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to write the output of a for loop to a `dataframe`

```
url_base = 'https://testurl.ca/contacts.php?t='    
url_title = ['new','notcontacted',
               'engage',
               'showing',
               'offers',] 
d = []
for url in url_title:
    print(url)
    url = url_base+ url
    br.open(url)
 
    html_doc = br.response().read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')
    mydivs = soup.find_all('div', [ 'card-name', 'card-activities','card-last-seen','activity-value',])
    st=''
    for div in mydivs:
        if re.search('^\([0-9][0-9][0-9]\)', div.text):
            st+=f'{div.text}\n'
        else:
            st+=f'{div.text}, '



    print(st)
```

**Result of the `for loop`**

```
new    
Daniel Brown, Online: 4 days ago New , wwe@yahoo.com, (111) 212-6765
Parik Wilson, Online: 3 days ago New , zxs@yahoo.com, (232) 456-1453

notcontacted
eeew trtr, Inquired: 2 days ago, Value $864,000 New , sdfs@icloud.com, (111) 500-1111
Yusuf Yusuf, Inquired: 2 days ago, Value $509,000 New , asdf@yahoo.com, (213) 111-9610
Jim Ricard, Next: Jun 27, 2020 @ 11:18 am New , ger@yahoo.com, (232) 111-6357
Reza Wilson, Online: 3 days ago New , 4rf@yahoo.com, (342) 456-7890
```

I want the results to be a pandas dataframe.

I tried to create an empty list and write the output to the dataframe but so far no luck.

```
x = 1
d = {}
c = ['Name','Online','Inquired','Value', 'Email','Phone']
df = pd.DataFrame(list(d.items()), columns=c)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why not store the results of for loop in a dict, and then use `pd.DataFrame.from_dict` method?

Comment: Not sure how to do that yet

Comment: I am not sure I understand the problem. The data seems fairly structured. Why not split on the commas and store the values in a dict?